# Could not run build action using Gradle installation

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy, netbeans, netbeans-platform

My setup contains:

- Netbeans 11.3
- OpenJDK 8
- Ubuntu 18.04

I used Netbean's git option as shown below in order to clone [this](https://github.com/GMOD/Apollo) project. However, after the below steps I got `Could not run build action using Gradle installation`:

[image: Could not run build action using Gradle installation]

**Step 1**
[image]

**Step 2**
[image]

**Step 3**
[image]

**Step 4**
[image]

**Step 5**
[image]

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: it says it can't find `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` on [line 59](https://github.com/GMOD/Apollo/blob/develop/build.gradle#L59) which tries to load `Config.groovy`  I suspect you are running with the wrong base directory

Comment: @tim_yates seems right. btw, user977828 What's your Grails version?

Comment: I installed it with sdkman (sdk install `grails 2.5.5`; sdk install `gradle 2.11`; sdk install `groovy`). How do I change the base directory?